# Swift / CollectionViewWaterfallLayout / how to set cell amount

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this [CollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/ecerney/CollectionViewWaterfallLayout).

The following functions sets the size of the cells randomly:

```
    var testInteger = 10

lazy var cellSizes: [CGSize] = {
    var _cellSizes = [CGSize]()

    for _ in 0...10 {
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform((UInt32(100))))

        _cellSizes.append(CGSize(width: 140, height: 50 + random))
    }

    return _cellSizes
}()
```

This: `for _ in 0...10` sets the amount of the cells to 10, but since I'm downloading data from a web blog, I need to set it by `var posts = [EventPosts]()` -> `posts.count`, to be the amount of blog entrys that are downloaded. How can I do that?

I've tryed to use `for _ in Int(posts.count)`, but it says, that *Instant Member posts, can't be used on type ViewControllerXY*.

Help is very appreciated.

Edit. This is the Custom Layout class.

```
    //
//  CollectionViewWaterfallLayout.swift
//  CollectionViewWaterfallLayout
//
//  Created by Eric Cerney on 7/21/14.
//  Based on CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout by Nelson Tai
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Eric Cerney. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

public let CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionHeader = "CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionHeader"
public let CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionFooter = "CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionFooter"

@objc public protocol CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate:UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize

    optional func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> Float

    optional func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> Float

    optional func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSection section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

    optional func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

    optional func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

    optional func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSection section: Int) -> Float

}

public class CollectionViewWaterfallLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    //MARK: Private constants
    /// How many items to be union into a single rectangle
    private let unionSize = 20;

    //MARK: Public Properties
    public var columnCount:Int = 2 {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(oldValue, newValue: columnCount)
        }
    }
    public var minimumColumnSpacing:Float = 10.0 {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(oldValue, newValue: minimumColumnSpacing)
        }
    }
    public var minimumInteritemSpacing:Float = 10.0 {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(oldValue, newValue: minimumInteritemSpacing)
        }
    }
    public var headerHeight:Float = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(oldValue, newValue: headerHeight)
        }
    }
    public var footerHeight:Float = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(oldValue, newValue: footerHeight)
        }
    }
    public var headerInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: oldValue), newValue: NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: headerInset))
        }
    }
    public var footerInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: oldValue), newValue: NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: footerInset))
        }
    }
    public var sectionInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero {
        didSet {
            invalidateIfNotEqual(NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: oldValue), newValue: NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: sectionInset))
        }
    }

    //MARK: Private Properties
    private weak var delegate: CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate?  {
        get {
            return collectionView?.delegate as? CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate
        }
    }
    private var columnHeights = [Float]()
    private var sectionItemAttributes = [[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()
    private var allItemAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    private var headersAttribute = [Int: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    private var footersAttribute = [Int: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    private var unionRects = [CGRect]()


    //MARK: UICollectionViewLayout Methods
    override public func prepareLayout() {
        super.prepareLayout()

        let numberOfSections = collectionView?.numberOfSections()

        if numberOfSections == 0 {
            return;
        }

        assert(delegate!.conformsToProtocol(CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate), "UICollectionView's delegate should conform to WaterfallLayoutDelegate protocol")
        assert(columnCount > 0, "WaterfallFlowLayout's columnCount should be greater than 0")

        // Initialize variables
        headersAttribute.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        footersAttribute.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        unionRects.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        columnHeights.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        allItemAttributes.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        sectionItemAttributes.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        for _ in 0..<columnCount {
            self.columnHeights.append(0)
        }

        // Create attributes
        var top:Float = 0
        var attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

        for section in 0..<numberOfSections! {
            /*
            * 1. Get section-specific metrics (minimumInteritemSpacing, sectionInset)
            */
            var minimumInteritemSpacing: Float
            if let height = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView!, layout: self, minimumInteritemSpacingForSection: section) {
                minimumInteritemSpacing = height
            }
            else {
                minimumInteritemSpacing = self.minimumInteritemSpacing
            }

            var sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets
            if let inset = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView!, layout: self, insetForSection: section) {
                sectionInset = inset
            }
            else {
                sectionInset = self.sectionInset
            }

            let width = Float(collectionView!.frame.size.width - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right)
            let itemWidth = floorf((width - Float(columnCount - 1) * Float(minimumColumnSpacing)) / Float(columnCount))

            /*
            * 2. Section header
            */
            var headerHeight: Float
            if let height = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView!, layout: self, heightForHeaderInSection: section) {
                headerHeight = height
            }
            else {
                headerHeight = self.headerHeight
            }

            var headerInset: UIEdgeInsets
            if let inset = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView!, layout: self, insetForHeaderInSection: section) {
                headerInset = inset
            }
            else {
                headerInset = self.headerInset
            }

            top += Float(headerInset.top)

            if headerHeight > 0 {
                attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionHeader, withIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section))
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: headerInset.left, y: CGFloat(top), width: collectionView!.frame.size.width - (headerInset.left + headerInset.right), height: CGFloat(headerHeight))

                headersAttribute[section] = attributes
                allItemAttributes.append(attributes)

                top = Float(CGRectGetMaxY(attributes.frame)) + Float(headerInset.bottom)
            }

            top += Float(sectionInset.top)
            for idx in 0..<columnCount {
                columnHeights[idx] = top
            }


            /*
            * 3. Section items
            */
            let itemCount = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)
            var itemAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

            // Item will be put into shortest column.
            for idx in 0..<itemCount {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: idx, inSection: section)
                let columnIndex = shortestColumnIndex()

                let xOffset = Float(sectionInset.left) + Float(itemWidth + minimumColumnSpacing) * Float(columnIndex)
                let yOffset = columnHeights[columnIndex]
                let itemSize = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView!, layout: self, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
                var itemHeight: Float = 0.0
                if itemSize?.height > 0 && itemSize?.width > 0 {
                    itemHeight = Float(itemSize!.height) * itemWidth / Float(itemSize!.width)
                }

                attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(xOffset), y: CGFloat(yOffset), width: CGFloat(itemWidth), height: CGFloat(itemHeight))
                itemAttributes.append(attributes)
                allItemAttributes.append(attributes)
                columnHeights[columnIndex] = Float(CGRectGetMaxY(attributes.frame)) + minimumInteritemSpacing
            }

            sectionItemAttributes.append(itemAttributes)

            /*
            * 4. Section footer
            */
            var footerHeight: Float
            let columnIndex = longestColumnIndex()
            top = columnHeights[columnIndex] - minimumInteritemSpacing + Float(sectionInset.bottom)

            if let height = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView!, layout: self, heightForFooterInSection: section) {
                footerHeight = height
            }
            else {
                footerHeight = self.footerHeight
            }

            var footerInset: UIEdgeInsets
            if let inset = delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView!, layout: self, insetForFooterInSection: section) {
                footerInset = inset
            }
            else {
                footerInset = self.footerInset
            }

            top += Float(footerInset.top)

            if footerHeight > 0 {
                attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionFooter, withIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section))
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: footerInset.left, y: CGFloat(top), width: collectionView!.frame.size.width - (footerInset.left + footerInset.right), height: CGFloat(footerHeight))

                footersAttribute[section] = attributes
                allItemAttributes.append(attributes)

                top = Float(CGRectGetMaxY(attributes.frame)) + Float(footerInset.bottom)
            }

            for idx in 0..<columnCount {
                columnHeights[idx] = top
            }
        }

        // Build union rects
        var idx = 0
        let itemCounts = allItemAttributes.count

        while idx < itemCounts {
            let rect1 = allItemAttributes[idx].frame
            idx = min(idx + unionSize, itemCounts) - 1
            let rect2 = allItemAttributes[idx].frame
            unionRects.append(CGRectUnion(rect1, rect2))
            ++idx
        }
    }

    override public func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        let numberOfSections = collectionView?.numberOfSections()
        if numberOfSections == 0 {
            return CGSizeZero
        }

        var contentSize = collectionView?.bounds.size
        contentSize?.height = CGFloat(columnHeights[0])

        return contentSize!
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        if indexPath.section >= sectionItemAttributes.count {
            return nil
        }

        if indexPath.item >= sectionItemAttributes[indexPath.section].count {
            return nil
        }

        return sectionItemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(elementKind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        var attribute: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?

        if elementKind == CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionHeader {
            attribute = headersAttribute[indexPath.section]
        }
        else if elementKind == CollectionViewWaterfallElementKindSectionFooter {
            attribute = footersAttribute[indexPath.section]
        }

        return attribute
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var begin:Int = 0
        var end: Int = unionRects.count
        var attrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for i in 0..<unionRects.count {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, unionRects[i]) {
                begin = i * unionSize
                break
            }
        }
        for i in (0..<unionRects.count).reverse() {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, unionRects[i]) {
                end = min((i+1) * unionSize, allItemAttributes.count)
                break
            }
        }
        for var i = begin; i < end; i++ {
            let attr = allItemAttributes[i]
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, attr.frame) {
                attrs.append(attr)
            }
        }

        return Array(attrs)
    }

    override public func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        let oldBounds = collectionView?.bounds
        if CGRectGetWidth(newBounds) != CGRectGetWidth(oldBounds!) {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func shortestColumnIndex() -> Int {
        var index: Int = 0
        var shortestHeight = MAXFLOAT

        for (idx, height) in columnHeights.enumerate() {
            if height < shortestHeight {
                shortestHeight = height
                index = idx
            }
        }

        return index
    }

    private func longestColumnIndex() -> Int {
        var index: Int = 0
        var longestHeight:Float = 0

        for (idx, height) in columnHeights.enumerate() {
            if height > longestHeight {
                longestHeight = height
                index = idx
            }
        }

        return index
    }

    private func invalidateIfNotEqual(oldValue: AnyObject, newValue: AnyObject) {
        if !oldValue.isEqual(newValue) {
            invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override this function:

```
override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

And then use this in `prepareLayout()`:

```
    // my collection only have one section,you can for-in all sections
    for row in 0..<collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {
        allLayoutAttributes.append(layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: row, inSection: 0))!)
    }
```

And return all attributes at last :

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    return allLayoutAttributes
}
```

Comment: the override gives me: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: I'm using a UIViewController and a UICollectionView, if that does change anything for the override

Comment: @DavidSeek Your layout should inherit from UICollectionViewLayout.

Comment: @DavidSeek And you should write these in that custom layout.

Comment: the custom layout does: `public class CollectionViewWaterfallLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {`

Comment: if I call it within my VC it tells me, that I call it multiple times

Comment: @DavidSeek Yeah,it is.And you should customize layout in CollectionViewWaterfallLayout.

Comment: @DavidSeek If you get new bug,please update your question with codes or ask a new question.

Comment: I'll try to understand at the moment... I've just added the custom layout class, maybe you'll see anything.